# Passing SessionSecurityToken between client and wcf services

Tags: asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication, token, wif

I have a problem with communication between client and wcf service application using federatedauthentication.

On my client application (ASP.NET MVC with Forms authentication) I pass the user data into claims, and build a SessionSecurityToken:

```
  SessionSecurityToken sessionSecurityToken = new
 SessionSecurityToken(transformedPrincipal,
 TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tokenLifeTime)); 
 sessionSecurityToken.IsReferenceMode = true;
 FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionSecurityToken);
```

tokenLifeTime is equal to 25 minutes.

On my services I'd like to read the cookie and get the user data stored in claims. However when I run following code on my services:

```
 SessionSecurityToken token;
 FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.TryReadSessionTokenFromCookie(out token);
```

The token is null.

**Update:**

I noticed that if I just create a service in the client application, the token is read without any problems. Also I can just set Httpcontext.Current.user and it works fine. However I do want to consume a service via service reference and in this scenario both HttpContext.Current.User is empty (but not null!) and cookie is not read as written above.